# Is it possible to redirect the example.com/index.php?page=abc to example.com/abc?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I Have a website which has `https://www.example.com/index.php?page=abc`
I want this URL to be open like this `https://www.example.com/teachers`
I have tried it through `.htaccess` redirect code but it returns "Page not found".

Below is my `.htaccess` code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=teachers($|&) 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /teachers? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes it is, but you must have made a mistake in your `.htaccess` coding. However you dont show us that. Would you like to add that to your question please.

Comment: code added please check

Answer (score 0):

For your teachers URL, you can use the following rule to convert your clean url to a .php file with a query string:

```
# URL
# INPUT https://www.example.com/teachers
# OUTPUT https://www.example.com/index.php?page=teachers

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

View on [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=435c8d58-8c4b-5a89-a3b5-f723b4dd6f18)

This allows user to visit `https://www.example.com/teachers`, and inside your `index.php` you can `$_GET['page']` to receive the `teachers` string.

Comment: it return Internal Server Error with the above htaccess code u mention

Comment: If you view the htaccess.madewithlove.be link above you will see how it works and that it is valid. It must of been something else inside your .htaccess that caused this error.